# Azure Powershell to read all the resources irrespective of its status or type

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am developing a powershell script to read all the azure resources (irrespective of its status or resource type) under a particular subscription. I have n number of subscriptions and a number of resources (such as DB, storage, Hosted Services, VM's, Cache etc) under each subscription. I know that I can read each resource and its status one by one through Azure Powershell.

This is actually used for auditing purpose and need to do it every two months.So, for simplicity I am automating this task. What I want to achieve is that: we have a tab named "All Items" in Azure Management Portal, where it lists all the resources of the selected subscription, irrespective of its status and types. I need to read the entire resource and its details (which includes status, its region etc etc) listed over there.

Tried Googling many times using many phrases, but no luck yet. Can someone offer me a hand for solving this in simple?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what information you need about each resource.

You can download the Azure PowerShell cmdlets (http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9811175&clcid=0x409)  and use Get-AzureResource to list all resources for a subscription, but this will just get the 'generic' resource data - the resource information shared by all resources, regardless of type.

To get the full data, you need a ResourceProvider-specific API version for each resource provider, and this information is a bit undiscoverable, you would have to hard code it into your script.

-Mark